# Can we do twitter authentication without firebase in flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, twitter-oauth, social-authentication

I just want to ask that can we do twitter authentication in flutter project without using firebase?

Comment: take a look, https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_login, https://www.developerlibs.com/2020/01/flutter-twitter-auth-login.html

Answer (score 0):

yes you can with  this package

https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_login#requirements

but you must have an account on twitter developers

Comment: https://towardsdev.com/flutter-login-with-twitter-oauth-v2-0-80e8d3a8959a 
 
article help you to do authentication in flutter project without using firebase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).